How to prove that $\left\|A^d\right\|\leq C\rho(A)\left\|A\right\|^{d-1}$ using Cayley-Hamilton?
If $A$ is a complex matrix, and $\rho(A)$ is its spectral Radius, then Jairo Bochi's answer to this question,
$$\left\|A^d\right\|\leq C\rho(A)\left\|A\right\|^{d-1};\quad (Eq.\, I)$$
where $C>0$.
He referred to this Ian Morris' question in which he used what he called by Cayley-Hamilton formula:
$$\sum_{k=0}^d (-1)^k\left(\mathrm{tr}\,A^{\wedge k}\right) A^{d-k}=0.$$
The thing is that I cannot find any reference to this formula and I even don't understand it. For example, I don't know what is $A^{\wedge k}$.
I don't need to understand Ian's proof or symbols. I just need a way to prove (Eq. I) from Cayley-Hamilton theorem.
I suppose it uses that CH proves that $A^d$ is a linear combination of $\{I,A,\cdots, A^{n-1}\}$.

$\mathrm{tr}\,A^{\wedge k}$ is just a fancy way to express the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial using exterior algebra. You may safely ignore it and just call it $c_k$.
Let $A$ be a $d\times d$ complex matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_d$. Its characteristic polynomial is
$$
p(x)=\det(xI-A)=(x-\lambda_1)\cdots(x-\lambda_d)=\sum_{k=0}^d(-1)^kc_kx^{d-k}
$$
where
$$
c_k=\sum_{i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k} \lambda_{i_1}\lambda_{i_2}\cdots\lambda_{i_k}.
$$
Since there are $\binom{d}{k}$ choices of the $k$-tuple $(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k)$ with strictly increasing indices, and $|\lambda|\leq\rho(A)\leq\|A\|$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, we have
$$
|c_k|
\leq\binom{d}{k}\rho(A)^k
\leq\binom{d}{k}\rho(A)\|A\|^{k-1}.\tag{1}
$$
Now, by Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $p(A)=0$. Therefore
$$
A^d=-\sum_{k=1}^d(-1)^kc_kA^{d-k}.
$$
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
\left\|A^d\right\|
&=\left\|-\sum_{k=1}^d(-1)^kc_kA^{d-k}\right\|\\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^d |c_k|\|A\|^{d-k}\\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^d \binom{d}{k}\rho(A)\|A\|^{d-1}\quad\text{by $(1)$}\\
&=(2^d-1)\rho(A)\|A\|^{d-1}.\\
\end{align*}
